# Add support for aws govCloud in rails applicatioin using gem 'aws-sdk'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I am working on AWS api based application where is working fine for all regions ,now i want to add the support aws govCloud(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/welcome.html)using aws-sdk api.

But when i try to call api using access key and secret token i am getting error "The security token included in the request is invalid" How can i access the govCloud using aws-sdk.

Comment: I have the same problem and question. Have you figured this out?

Comment: I have found the solution of this issue.below is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the region 'us-gov-west-1' while accessing the API of govCloud.

```
 @ec2 = AWS::EC2.new(access_key_id: 'Your Access Key', secret_access_key: 'Your S', region: 'us-gov-west-1')
response = @ec2.client.describe_instances
@instances = response.reservation_set.map(&:instances_set).flatten!
```

Using this code you can access the govCloud.